# Configurar locales en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
   $date = new DateTime($uh->updated_at);
   echo $date->format('d/M/Y');
?>
```

Necesito generar la fecha, basándome en el valor de una variable. Y que esta se genere en español. He intentado lo siguiente, pero no he podido pasar como argumento la fecha que yo quiera.

```
<?php
   setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
   echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y");
?>
```

Como puedo pasar una variable con una fecha dinámica y que esta se imprima en Español?

Comment: como segundo parámetro, `echo strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y" , $date->getTimestamp());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Empezamos con el codigo

Podrias bien intentar algo asi:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");

/* HOY */
$fecha = new DateTime();
print strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y", $fecha->getTimestamp()) . "\n";

/* En una semana */
$fecha = new DateTime("2017-08-04");
print strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y", $fecha->getTimestamp()) . "\n";

?>
```

Resultado

> viernes 28 de julio del 2017
>
> viernes 04 de agosto del 2017

### Que hemos hecho?

Analizando las funciones que estamos usando para la **generacion de la fecha**, en este caso **[strftime()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php)**, podemos encontrar que los **[parametros de esta funcion](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php#refsect1-function.strftime-parameters)** son:

- **formato**
- **timestamp**

Si bien el formato lo podemos encontrar en la **[documentacion de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php#refsect1-function.strftime-parameters)**. El parametro `timestamp` lo podemos obtener en la clase **[DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.gettimestamp.php)**, lo cual nos devuelve *la cantidad de segundos transcurridos desde el 1 de Enero de 1970*. Este parametro es usado por la funcion **[strftime()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php)** para poder generar un mensaje de acuerdo al formato especificado.

Comment: Ok, Muchas gracias, ya me queda claro.

Comment: Otra pregunta: en el siente ejercicio: $number = ($uh->price_normal);

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_ES');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n"; -- se produce este error:money_format() expects parameter 2 to be double, string given. ¿Que está mal?

Comment: Te recomiendo que escribas una pregunta nueva, asi sera mas facil ayudarte